# Unexpected value 'ButtonModule Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular

i have made a UI Library in Angular 8 and am using this library into my another custom library, But when am importing my modules from parent library it throws this error `Unexpected value 'DefaultButtonModule Please add a @NgModule annotation .`
`angular cli : 8.3.0`
`node: 10.15.0`
am using these versions.

I have tried white listing non peer dependencies and exporting modules. 
Am using Angular material in my parent library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export and import the files explicitly.

If it's a module file it is to imported from the .module file i.e,

```
import {Module} from './path/file.module'
```

If you keep all exports in the index.ts file make sure you also specify /index in the path when you're importing i.e,

```
export * from './path/index
```